# Family over the coarse moduli space of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, coarse-moduli-spaces

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. As the coarse moduli space of curves $M_g$ of genus $g$ over $k$ is not a fine moduli space, it does not have a universal family. But I am wondering if it has a family (proper and flat) such that the fiber over every point $[C]$ of $M_g$ is isomorphic to the curve $C$.

As a disclaimer: I am not that familiar with the language of stacks. As far as I understand the situation in this context, the stack $\mathcal{M}_g$ has an universal family $\mathcal{C}_g$. The corresponding coarse moduli space of $\mathcal{C}_g$ is $M_{g,1}$, so the coarse moduli space of curves with one marked point. The morphism $\pi \colon M_{g,1} \to M_g$ on the level of quasiprojective varieties is just forgetting about the marked point. This family has the property that the fiber over a point $[C]$ is isomorphic to $C$, at least if $C$ has no nontrivial automorphisms. In all other cases the fiber is isomorphic to $C/\operatorname{Aut}(C)$. Is it possible to get something better than that?

Comment: If you had such a family, then you'd get a section of the map $\mathcal{M}_g$ to $M_g$, and also a map from the total space of the family to $\mathcal{C}_g$.

Comment: There is the forgetful morphism from the coarse moduli space $M_{g,1}$ to $M_g$.  However, that morphism is not everywhere flat.

Comment: @ulrich Is this something that should not exist?

Comment: My previous comment would imply that there is a morphism from any family (as in the question) to $M_{g,1}$ which on fibres is the quotient by the automorphism group. This morphism would be finite birational and this is not possible since $M_{g,1}$ is normal. (I am assuming that $g \geq 3$.)

Answer (score 1):

To close up loose ends and for everyone finding this questions: Such a family does not exist in general. An argument for elliptic curves can be found in Robin Hartshorne Deformation Theory in Remark 26.3.1.